# Phrase for action "testing and correcting"

Tags: colloquialisms

What is a phrase to indicate the action *testing and correcting*? For example, imagine a situation in which you don't know what you should do exactly and step by step you change things and see the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [trial and error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_and_error).

Answer (score 0):

Some related terms:

- *[cut and try](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cut-and-try)* - "marked by trial and error; *cut–and–try methods*, *cut–and–try testing*.  First Known Use 1903."
- *[hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing)* - "...starts with an arbitrary solution to a problem, then attempts to find a better solution by incrementally changing [elements] of the solution. If the change produces a better solution, an incremental change is made to the new solution..." Note, *[gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)* methods are related to hill climbing.
- *[kaizen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizen)*, a continual<sup>1</sup> improvement process, via a Plan - Do - Check - Act cycle, somewhat like using a series of small testing-and-correcting steps.

Note 1: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continual_improvement_process#.22Continuous.22_versus_.22continual.22) indicates *continual* is preferred to *continuous* here.

Answer (score 0):

In Programming it is reffered to as debugging

> de·bug  (d-bg)
>
> tr.v. de·bugged, de·bug·ging, de·bugs
>
> 1. To search for and eliminate malfunctioning elements or errors in: debug a spacecraft before launch; debug a computer program.